# Post Message on Friends Facebook Wall post

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am working on Application in which i have to post Greeting to my friends Wall post through My Account.

So How can i Perform it ? If anyone have idea Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 NSMutableDictionary *parmaDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
[parmaDic setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello world"] forKey:@"message"]; // if you want send message  
[parmaDic setObject:@"http://icon.png" forKey:@"picture"];  // if you want send picture    
[parmaDic setObject:@"Create post" forKey:@"name"];         // if you want send name    
[parmaDic setObject:@"Write description." forKey:@"description"]; // if you want  description

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/feed",facebook_user_id] 
                      andParams:parmaDic 
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

I use key like.message,picture ..etc please see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 1):

Take Dictionary first in which add your data which you want to post on your friends's Wall as:-

```
NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//posting the text written in the textView   
[postVariablesDictionary setObject:self.TextView.text forKey:@"message"];

[objDelegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",friendId] andParams:postVariablesDictionary andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];
```

Thats how the data would be posted on friend's wall.
Hope it helps Thanks :)