# Posting On facebook friends wall

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anybody tell me how to post on facebook friends wall using Facebook SDK 3.2 or 3.5??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? This question shows little to no research. Questions that show little to no research aren't good questions. Please provide us with what you have looked at or some code that you have tried. Help us help you. -1

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685970/how-to-post-message-on-facebook-friends-wall-in-iphone, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209217/facebook-api-post-message-on-friends-wall, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172662/post-message-on-friends-facebook-wall-post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773030/facebook-api-post-on-friend-wall

Comment: Yep, that is a question of [pure greatness](http://twilight.ponychan.net/chan/files/src/136795371879.gif)

Answer (score 4):

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"Friend FB id", @"to",
                                   @"Say Hello",  @"message",
                                   @"Your Descriptive message", @"description",
                                   @"Your link", @"link",
                                   @"Your photo link", @"picture",
                                   @"Facebook app id",@"app_id"
                                   @"feed",@"method"
                                   nil];
```

Prepare Dictionary with These much Parameter and Then Call Method

```
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:session//[FBSession activeSession]
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:
         ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error){
}];
```

Make sure that Before calling this your facebook Session should be valid.

Comment: What is the url used for this facebook.com/me   correct?

Comment: How to pass multiple friends ids in "to" => value